# I have a dataset in mongodb.I want to perform some functions coded in python.How do I perform those functions on it(i.e.bar graph of the given data)

Tags: python, mongodb, connectivity

```
use indbar1
db.branch.insert({ "name" : "b1" , "y2000" : 80 , "y2001" : 105 })
```

Given above is the clip of database and collection name and how the type of data looks

Comment: Please post required o/p

Comment: I want to find the graph of branches b1,b2,b3,b4,b5 and b6 which has y2000 and y2001 data.The graph should have two bars y2000 and y2001 for each branch.Later I will find ratios between different branches which depends on the set of questions given to me in my assignment.(The x axis is branch name and the y axis is value.)

Comment: Let's say if you've `{ "name" : "b1" , "y2000" : 80 , "y2001" : 105 }, { "name" : "b1" , "y2000" : 80 , "y2001" : 105 },{ "name" : "b2" , "y2000" : 80 , "y2001" : 105 }`, Do you want output as `{ "x" : "b1" , "y2000" : 160 , "y2001" : 210 },{ "x" : "b2" , "y2000" : 80 , "y2001" : 105 }` ?

Comment: Yes......Exactly what I want

Comment: @whoami Ya it is working. Sorz for not responding and thnx a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Match docs where both fields exists */
  {
    $match: {
      "y2000": {
        $exists: true
      },
      "y2001": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  /** Group branches & sum up each fields values across all docs */
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      y2000: {
        $sum: "$y2000"
      },
      y2001: {
        $sum: "$y2001"
      }
    }
  },
  /** Transform fields to required format */
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      x: "$_id",
      y2000: 1,
      y2001: 1
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nRRQh4t6-gz)